# BASH: parse a variable with awk

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a variable that contains the result of the command `whereis ls` which is:

```
ls: /bin/ls /usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.gz
```

I need to search through this variable and retrieve this specific portion and save it into a new variable, newVar:

```
/bin
```

I have tried `echo $var | awk '{print $2}'`
but this grabs `/bin/ls`

I then need to search through my $PATH variable finding the substring /bin: (I was thinking with my newVar as a match somehow) and somehow remove this portion of $PATH and update $PATH to reflect that change. 
Quite new to bash scripting and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is output of `type ls` ?

Comment: @anubhava i'm not too sure what you mean, when i run type ls on my terminal i get ```ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'```

Comment: Try: `whereis ls | awk '{sub(/\/ls$/, "", $2); print $2}'`

Comment: @anubhava that worked! thank you so much, could I trouble to break the part inside the awk execution block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might just use `dirname` and `which`:

```
dirname "$(which ls)"
```

Comment: Glad it helped! PS: there is also `basename`, it's the opposite and gives you the filename without the path.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ echo "$var" | cut -d/ -f2
bin
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `awk`:

```
whereis ls | awk '{sub(/\/ls$/, "", $2); print $2}'
```

`sub` function strips trailing `/ls` from 2nd column of `whereis` output.